# VBA - Worksheet_Calculate event triggers over and over again

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to update a column (E8:E508) with the contents of another reference column (G8:G508) each time the reference column changes, using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("G8:G503")
    If Not Intersect(Rng, Range("G8:G503")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E8:E503") = Range("G8:G503").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The code works as intended, but appears to be running over and over again and eventually crashes Excel.

Comment: it makes no sense that you are using this command `Intersect(Rng, Rng)` .... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Understandable, I'm new to VBA. I am using that function to limit the Worksheet_Calculate event to that range - i.e. only a change to a cell within that range will trigger the event.

Comment: i think that you want the `worksheet_change` event, not the `worksheet_calculate` event

Comment: The reference column (G8:G503) is a column of formulas, rather than manual values - hence the Calculate function (Change didn't work).

Comment: after this line `Set Rng = Range("G8:G503")`, use `Rng` in your code, not `Range("G8:G503")`

Comment: That also works, but again the issue is the same - the code appears to run over and over until the workbook crashes.

Comment: `Range("E8:E503") = Range("G8:G503").Value` triggers another calculation, etc, etc.  You need `Application.EnableEvents = False` before doing that (and set back to True after)

Comment: Where specifically do I need those lines? I've tried to do add those but in all instances the code has stopped working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Range("E8:E503") = Range("G8:G503").Value
```

triggers another calculation, which triggers your event handler, etc etc.

To prevent that endless cycle you need to temporarily disable events before doing that (and then re-enable after)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("E8:E503").Value = Range("G8:G503").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("G8:G503")

    If Not Intersect(Rng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E8:E503") = Rng.Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: oh, my bad ... sorry ... you want to update when formula result changes, not when data is entered

Comment: why use VBA code?  put `=G8` into cell `E8` then copy and paste all way down to `E503`